# Firestore Flutter : get querySnapshot.length & set new doc

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, future

I'm creating a Coffe Shop App. I have this firestore structure.
I need that the family of products could be orderer by the user, so  the structure is:

```
Products: {
   Coffee:{
     subcollection(), 
     'FamilyOrder: int'}, 
   Sandwiches: {
     subcollection(), 
     'FamilyOrder: int'},
   ...}
```

THe code I'm working on to create each Family is:

```
CollectionReference dbProducts =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Products");
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormBuilderState>();
  Future<void> getOrder() {
    return dbProducts.get().then((querySnapshot) {
      setState(() {
        DataBaseFields.order = querySnapshot.docs.length;
      });
      print(DataBaseFields.order);
    });
  }

  Future<void> addFamily() {
    _formKey.currentState!.save();
    return dbProducts
        .doc(DataBaseFields.name.toString())
        .set({
          "FamilyOrder ": DataBaseFields.order,
        })
        .then((value) => print("Family Added"))
        .catchError((error) => print("Failed to add Family: $error"));
  }
```

I don't know what's happening, somehow works and later stops working.
I think the problem is that Future addFamily() depends on a Future getOrder().
But I don't how to make a single call or wait till getOrder ends.

when stops working, it adds 'FamilyOrder': null. But then prints the correct value.
[image: firestore screenshot]

[image: screenshot_firestore]

Answer (score 0):

ok,..I anidate the set call inside the query return,.. And it works

```
 Future<void> getOrder() {
        _formKey.currentState!.save();
        return dbProducts.get().then((querySnapshot) {
          setState(() {
            DataBaseFields.order = querySnapshot.docs.length;
          });
          print(DataBaseFields.order);
    
          return dbProducts
              .doc(DataBaseFields.name.toString())
              .set({
                "FamilyOrder ": DataBaseFields.order,
              })
              .then((value) => print("Family Added"))
              .catchError((error) => print("Failed to add Family: $error"));
        });
      }
```